# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API not hitting any of the configured routes, why is that?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created BaseController that looks like this

```
`[ApiController]
  public class MoviesPlaceBaseController : ControllerBase
  {
    protected readonly IMoviesPlaceSupervisor _moviesPlaceSupervisor;

    public MoviesPlaceBaseController(IMoviesPlaceSupervisor moviesPlaceSupervisor)    
    {
        _moviesPlaceSupervisor = moviesPlaceSupervisor;
    }`
```

In my "PostController" I derive from that base controller class which looks like this

```
`    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class PostController : MoviesPlaceBaseController
    {
      public PostController(IMoviesPlaceSupervisor supervisor) : base (supervisor){ }

        // GET api/post
        [HttpGet]
        [Produces(typeof(List<PostViewModel>))]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<PostViewModel>>> Get(CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
        {
          return new ObjectResult(await _moviesPlaceSupervisor.GetAllPostsAsync(ct));
        }`
```

My launchSettings.json I removed the https url and it now looks like this

```
`"MoviesPlaceAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }`
```

my Startup.cs ConfigureServices looks like this

```
` public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

      services.AddConnectionProvider(Configuration)
        .ConfigureSupervisor()
        .AddMiddleware()
        .AddCorsConfiguration()
        .ConfigureRepositories();
    }`
```

When running my application I cannot hit my api/post route. When I put break points in that action and run the app, the breakpoint says its "unverified". I tried doing api/post and api/posts. In the controller class i removed the Route["controller"] with just the name of the controller "post", but same thing. The weird thing is that I can hit api/values just fine, even though that controller no longer exists in my app. I have no idea what is going on, can someone shed some light please.

Comment: You might need to Cleans soultion -> clear out the bin folder, Rebuild

Comment: did you renamed `ValuesController` to `PostController`?

Comment: I forgot to add that I did that, and unfortunately I get the same thing. Very strange. A reference is still somewhere.

Comment: Yes I did do that. I renamed values controller to post controller. How does that effect things if the class name is changed and the file name itself has changed.

Comment: can you add a new controller and move your code to and try ( remove old one)

Comment: I just did that.       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/post1  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/post1  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 3.3409ms 404 .... same thing

Comment: api/values still works...

Comment: I think I see the issue. I had upgraded my asp.net core project from 2.1 to 2.2. The binary for 2.1 was still in the debug folder and I bet it was hitting those dlls instead of the new ones. Im fixing it now. I think that will resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my project from asp.net core 2.1 to 2.2 When I performed clean then build. It did not entirely get rid of the previously compiled code. My launch.json file was still pointing to Debug/netcoreapp.2.1... after changing that to 2.2 everything started working as expected.